# Not able to RDP to the VM which is part of new subnet in Azure virtual network

Tags: vpn, firewall, azure

Here are my environment detail

I am using Azure **IaaS** (Infrastructure as Service)
I am having one **vNet** (Virtual Network)
I have set-up **site to site** connectivity (on-premise to azure)
I have one subnet and couple of VMs in in it. (**VM01 and VM02**)
I am able to RDP **VM01 and VM02** from my local machine (via VPIN). But now I have created new subnet, also added couple of VMs to it (**VM03 and VM04**). These new VM's I am not able to RDP.

Note: I can RDP to **VM03 and VM04** by going inside **VM01 and VM02**!

Is there any difference between first subnet and the one which created later? As first subnet created by network administrator I am not sure if he has done any configuration in on-premise to understand the subnets.

**Update** : I am able to ping but can not connect. so I moved my question from **Network engineering** to **server fault**.

Comment: Are there any network security groups configured on subnet 2?

Comment: I figured out that new IP range which allocated to subnet 2 is not mapped with on premise. I have asked network admin to configure it. hopefully it will be resolved.